# Working locally with git and remote with subversion

Tags: git, svn

I really like `git`but unfortunately only can submit to a `subversion` repository.

Is it possible to work locally with `git`with all benefits and submit/checkout from a `subversion` repository?

Comment: You can't have both full benefits of git and keep using SVN server at the same time. That's because some things don't translate nicely from git to SVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just appeared on Hackernews: [Working with git on a Subversion project](http://vbsteven.com/archives/587)

Comment: Page linked in this answer can't be found :(

Comment: There's a version on archive.org but the server is down right now: https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.stevenvanbael.com/archives/587

Answer (score 4):

git [integrates nicely](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/) with subversion.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this ProGit chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion#Committing-Back-to-Subversion) particularly useful.

> One of Git’s great features is a bidirectional bridge to Subversion called git svn. This tool allows you to use Git as a valid client to a Subversion server, so you can use all the local features of Git and then push to a Subversion server as if you were using Subversion locally.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Three's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9341789/1330180) [answer](https://www.viget.com/articles/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/):

> This just appeared on Hackernews: Working with git on a Subversion project

## Getting Started

Using [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) (Official) you can clone your SVN repository using the command

```
git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir
```

> The -s is there to signify that my Subversion repository has a standard layout (trunk/, branches/, and tags/.) If your repository doesn’t have a standard layout, you can leave that off.

This tracks everything except empty directories as git doesn't track empty directories and `svn:ignore` is not ignored in this git repo. To add these files to a `.gitignore` file, run the following command.

```
git-svn show-ignore > .gitignore
```

You can then use the commands such as `git checkout -b new_branch_name [old_branch_name]` for adding branches, `git add <filename>` for adding files, `git checkout <filename>` for reverting changes and `git commit -a` for committing changes as you would normally use git.

Before committing back to svn, you will want to rebase any changes using `git-svn rebase` and then to push your commits back to svn you will use `git-svn dcommit` (Delta Commit).